# golang package exec issues

Tags: go, exec

I am having trouble using the go exec package.

I am receiving this error :

```
'\"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

When I try to run this code in golang on a Windows machine:

```
package main

import (
"os/exec"
"fmt"
)

func main() {
 var CMD string = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe\" C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Guess.py"
 //var CMD string = `"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" C:\Users\User\Desktop\Guess.py`
 ExecCMD := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", CMD)
 out, _ := ExecCMD.CombinedOutput()
 fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/xBqjSMHFu5Z

Comment: Please can anyone help me? I am kinda of stuck!

Comment: Any reason that you're calling `cmd` rather than executing the editor directly? Not a Windows guy so maybe I'm missing something obvious but running  shell to run something else tends to be a recipe for a confusing mess of quotes and escaped quotes.

Comment: If I don't call in cmd then I cannot run built in commands like "mkdir" "dir" etc..

Comment: I am trying to create like my own program that executes system commands! Using the package "bufio" I want to create a reader that takes in user input and executes it. I would like one syntax that would work for all kinds of possibilities! --jrefior-- showed me code that would solve one trouble but not the rest!

Answer (score 1):

You're passing two executables ("cmd" and "...sublime_text.exe") when you probably only want one.  The `exec` package doesn't use the shell, so take out all your quotes and escapes.  Pass each argument as a separate argument in exec.Command.

In other words, this:

```
 exe := `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe`
 file := `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Guess.py`
 ExecCMD := exec.Command(exe, file)
```

Comment: This Works! Yes! How would I run this command then "mkdir test" and built in cmd commands?. I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Isn't there one syntax that will work on all sorts of problem?

Comment: The os package contains Mkdir and MkdirAll functions
https://golang.org/pkg/os/#MkdirAll

Comment: I appreciate all your efforts! What about tasklist and taskill? I am speaking about all cmd built in commands.

Comment: That's more complicated.  There's a lot you can do with Go standard library and other Go packages.  And then there's windows-specific commands and scripting, which I'm not an expert on and I prefer Linux.  I suggest researching your question and if you can't find the answer, then ask it as a new question, as it is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I appreciate it!